# Erro na instalação/execução do WampServer 2.5

Tags: instalador, wamp

Instalei o WampServer 2.5 64bits e durante a instalação não ocorreu nenhum erro, porém ao executar aparece a seguinte mensagem.

> **The configuration file contains a syntax error on line 325: [EParseError] Parameter "Service" specifies an unknown service**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No arquivo de configuração nessa linha constam essas informações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual modificação deve ser feita nessa linha para que o Wamp execute sem problemas?

Windows 7 SP1 - 64bits

**edit**

parte do arquivo

```
324 [switchApache2.2.22]
325 Action: service; Service: ; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
326 Action: run; FileName: "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/bin/httpd.exe"; Parameters: "-n wampapache -k uninstall"; ShowCmd: hidden; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
```

Olhando no GitHub pude perceber que o meu arquivo está sem as informações no service, porém não tenho certeza de qual informação de ser adicionada neste local.
[Segue o link da pesquisa](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ServiceAction%3A%20stop%3B%20Flags%3A%20ignoreerrors%20waituntilterminated&type=Code&ref=searchresults)

Answer (score 1):

Experimente adicionar o serviço do Apache:

```
324 [switchApache2.2.22]
325 Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
326 Action: run; FileName: "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/bin/httpd.exe"; Parameters: "-n wampapache -k uninstall"; ShowCmd: hidden; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
```

Comment: Eu fiz isso e então ele gera um erro na próxima linha.

Answer (score 1):

Lhe faço a seguinte recomendação:

1. Faça backup da pasta `c:\wamp\www`
2. Faça backup tabelas pelo usando no `cmd` (altere a pasta `mysql5.5.24` conforme a necessidade)

   - Primeiro visualise as tabelas com o comando:

     ```
     cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\
     mysql -u root -p -e "select table_name"
     ```
   - Depois faça o backup das tabelas que você criou usando o seguinte comando:

     ```
     cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\
     mysqldump NOME_DA_TABELA > c:\Users\Nome do usuario\Desktop\nome_da_tabela.sql
     ```
3. Remova o wamp completamente
4. Baixe-o novamente pelo link http://www.wampserver.com/en/
5. Restaure a pasta `www` e os `.sql` salvos você pode restaurar pelo phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente a instalação do Wampserver tanto 32bits quanto 64bits não deveria apresentar problema no momento da sua execução. O problema pode ser algum antivírus ou vírus ou os dois juntos. Se seu pc tem Baiddu ou Hao123 ou barras de ferramentas que não se sabe de onde vem nos navegadores e as vezes até vários antivírus instalados entrando em conflito. tem que ver também se não está tentando instalar um software 64bits num sistema operacional 32bits.

Dependendo das versões dos softwares, pode ter problemas com portas também entre o Skype e o Wampserver tentando se conectar a mesma porta.

Comment: Esse não é o caso, mas obrigada.